# How to fix an 'ArgumentError: Cannot infer root key from collection type. Please specify the root or each_serializer option, or render a JSON String'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm passing an object to a serializer which return's all the records,when object returns empty array is the time where this error will show up.

```rb
def booked_cars
     if params["id"].present?
        @customer = Customer.find(params["id"].to_i)
        @booked_cars = @customer.bookings.where(cancelled: false).collect{|c| c.used_car}
        render json: @booked_cars, each_serializer: UsedCarSerializer
      end
end
```

I expect it to give array of objects or an empty array,instead gives an argument error (ArgumentError (Cannot infer root key from collection type. Please specify the root or each_serializer option, or render a JSON String):)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `serializer` option or `root` option as specified in the error response from active_model_serializer.

Because the serializer gets the root from the collection.

```
@customer = Customer.find(params["id"].to_i)
render json: @customer
```

In the above case, the serializer will respond like the below,

```
{ 
 "customer": #root
  {
   # attributes ...
  }
}
```

because the object is not a collection, so the root is in singular form(**customer**).

```
@customers = Customer.where(id: ids) # ids is an array of ids.
render json: @customer
```

In the above case, the serializer will respond like the below,

```
{ 
 "customers": #root
  {
   # attributes ...
  }
}
```

because the object is not a collection, so the root is in plural form(**customers**).

The serializer will add root based on the class of the object(ActiveRecord || ActiveRecordCollection).

If the object is empty array serializer can't predict which to use as a root. So we need to specify the **root** or **serializer** option.

```
render json: @customer, root: 'customer'
```

or

```
 render json: @customer, serializer: UsedCarSerializer
```

NOTE: Active model serializer detect the serializer either from the class of the object or from the serializer option.

Comment: Okay, but you don't need to add "root" key if the result is an active record object. Here in your code, it will return Array.

Comment: The query logic that you have used will produce N+1 queries.
`@booked_cars = UsedCar.where(id: @customer.bookings.where(cancelled: false).pluck(:used_car_id))` - This will just produce two queries. and you can even join two table for making a single query `UsedCar.joins(:booking).where('customer_id = ? and cancelled = false', @customer.id)` and make sure that @customer is present.

Comment: In both of the cases, adding root is not needed as the result is actually an active record collection.